# Using tf.exe in Powershell says All files are up to date

Tags: powershell, tfs

I am using Powershell to get the latest build label from TFS, and then fetch that latest build label into a specific directory.

Getting the latest build label works fine, like so:

```
Set-Location -Path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\'
$cmd = '.\tf.exe'
$arg1 = 'labels'
$arg2 = '/owner:*'
$arg3 = 'BLD_V3R11*'
$result = & $cmd $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 | Select-Object -Last 1
```

$result would be equal to something like

```
BLD_V3R11_1234
```

So now I try and fetch all files from that build like so, into c:\Compile folder

```
Set-Location -Path 'c:\Compile'
$cmd = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe'
$arg1 = 'get'
$arg2 = 'c:\Compile2\*'
$arg3 = '/recursive'
$arg4 = '/version:L' + $result
& $cmd $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4
```

However no files are pulled from TFS and the call returns 'All files are up to date.'

How can files be up to date when there are no files in c:\Compile ?

Answer (score 0):

Error "All files are up to date" usually happens if folder does not exists, you may specify the server path for the file or folder to retrieve, like `$arg2 = '$/teamProject/project/file.cs'`.

Comment: No, issue was I was trying to download them to a folder which was not mapped. TFS on the server could tell I had a copy of the files in another folder

Comment: If c:\Compile is not a correct workspace, you'll get "Unable to determine the workspace". The get command retrieves items from the server into a workspace. You need to create a workspace first.